# Closure Compiler issues warning with namespaced enum

Tags: google-closure-compiler

The following sample code generates a compiler warning on advanced optimization: "JSC_UNSAFE_NAMESPACE: incomplete alias created for namespace NS".  If I remove the @enum comment, it doesn't give the warning.

```
var NS = {};

/**
 * @enum {string}
 */
NS.type = {
    FOO : 'bar'
};

NS.foobar = function(){ alert(NS.type.FOO); };

window['NS'] = NS;
window['NS']['foobar'] = NS.foobar;
```

Exporting only the function and not the namespace also seems to work:

```
window['NS_foobar'] = NS.foobar;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way around this? I'd rather not include the Closure library if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler expects to collapse the enum value into single variables:

NS.type.FOO becomes NS$type$FOO.  The "NS" that you exported would not contain what you expect.

I suspect you want something like this:

```
window['NS'] = {}; // an external namespace object.
window['NS']['foobar'] = NS.foobar; // add 'foobar' to the external namespace.
```