# Closure Compiler: @enum, property collapsing and JSC_UNSAFE_NAMESPACE

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

## Initial situation

I have the following code:

```
var NS = {};  // namespace

NS.myEnum = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
};

var extendedNS = Object.create(NS);

extendedNS.myAlert = function (x) { alert(x); };

extendedNS.myAlert(extendedNS.myEnum.foo);
```

It compiles successfully with this command (no warnings or errors):

```
java -jar compiler-20150609.jar --js test.js --compilation_level ADVANCED --warning_level VERBOSE
```

## Question 1

According to the [docs for `JSC_UNSAFE_NAMESPACE`](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref), I think the Advanced optimisations may replace `NS.myEnum` with `NS$myEnum`, and then remove `NS`.

So why does the compiler **not** raise a warning for this line?

```
var extendedNS = Object.create(NS);
```

Isn't this an unsafe reference to the namespace `NS`? Shouldn't the compiler warn: *"incomplete alias created for namespace `NS`"*?

## @enum type breaks compiled output

I now mark `NS.myEnum` as an enum:

```
/**
 * @enum {number}
 */
NS.myEnum = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
};
```

According to [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8214977), *"the compiler expects to collapse the enum value into single variables"*. So I think the compiler may now collapse `NS.myEnum` to:

```
NS$myEnum$foo = 1;
NS$myEnum$bar = 2;
```

The compiler now raises a warning:

```
WARNING - incomplete alias created for namespace NS
var extendedNS = Object.create(NS);
                               ^
```

I think I understand why: the Advanced optimisations may have removed `NS` after collapsing the enum's values.

The compiled output is indeed broken:

```
var a = Object.create({});
a.a = function() {
  alert(a.c.b);      // a.c.b doesn't exist, so a runtime error will occur
};
a.a();
```

## Question 2

I now add a [`@nocollapse`](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tag-nocollapse) tag to the enum (*"Denotes a property that should not be collapsed by the compiler into a variable. If you annotate a property that is an object with `@nocollapse`, all its properties will also remain uncollapsed."*):

```
/**
 * @enum {number}
 * @nocollapse
 */
NS.myEnum = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
};
```

The compiled output is now valid code:

```
var a = Object.create({c:{a:1, f:2}});
a.b = function() {
  alert(a.c.a);      // a.c.a does exist
};
a.b();
```

But the compiler still raises a `JSC_UNSAFE_NAMESPACE` warning:

```
WARNING - incomplete alias created for namespace NS
var extended = Object.create(NS);
                             ^
```

Why? Is there another tag I need to add to `NS.myEnum` to prevent this warning?

(Note: I'd prefer not to `@suppress` the warning. I'd like to understand and fix the cause of the warning.)

Answer (score 1):

The core issue comes down to the fact that traditionally, `@enum` properties have  always been collapsed - thus the warning when the `@enum` annotation is added as code could be broken (and is in your first example).

`@nocollapse` does block enum collapsing and the warning is probably incorrectly emitted when that annotation is present. You can [file a bug](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues) about this if you wish, but it will probably be a low priority issue.

In the general case, enums are designed to be used more like constants and thus using them as the proto object is not an intended/supported behavior.

The rules and cases surrounding property collapsing are complex. The best way to understand them is look through the [unit tests](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/test/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CollapsePropertiesTest.java#L262) to see the specific patterns which trigger the warning.